# Is GTA Vice City for Android faithful to the original version?

Tags: ios, android, version-differences, grand-theft-auto-vice-city

I didn't play Vice City the first time around, and was just wondering how similar the new version (*versions* - I assume this question applies to iOS as well) is to the original.

Comment: It *is* the original...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same game, with slightly improved visuals and obviously modified for touch-screen control.

Answer (score 2):

Properties were double the price in the original and overall the game was a bit harder.